# Applying several stashes without commiting

Tags: git, git-stash

Is there anyway to apply various stashes in my currently checked out branch without having to do commits (and eventually resetting HEAD) in the process?

Answer (score 2):

There is no trick: just apply the stashes one after another.

If your stashes are correctly ordered in the stack you just need to proceed as follows:

```
git stash apply
git stash drop
```

Repeat this until you apply all stashes you need. You don't need to commit between apply and apply. If you want to save time a better command can be used: instead of first `apply` and then `drop` you can just `pop` the stash

```
git stash pop
```

If the stashes are not in a proper order then specify in the command which stash you want to apply or drop:

```
git stash apply <stash>
git stash drop <stash>
```

or

```
git stash pop <stash>
```

If you the stash apply gives a merge error it means that you are not allowed to apply this stash. So in that case **you cannot apply it until you commit your changes**. It is maybe ugly but it is the waz it works.

Comment: Note you can just use `git stash pop <stash>` if you're always doing both `apply` _and_ `drop`.